# What type of Cable Should I use between a Long Wire antenna and a Transmatch?

Tags: wire-antenna, mobile, impedance-matching, feed-line, end-fed-antenna

I installed a Yaesu System 600with a MFJ Versatuner 2 on my 31ft sailboat and Idont know what type of cable should I use between the MFJ and the long wire antenna I have on my back Stay.
Any suggestions?

Fernando from Buenos Aires, Argentina.

Comment: Hello Fernando, and welcome to this site! Please [edit your question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/posts/18254/edit) to include details of your antenna and how you are "grounding" it. For the benefit of those answering your question,  here is a link to [the instruction manual](http://www.w1npp.org/ares/redcross/yaesu_system_600_scanned_operating_manual.pdf) **PDF**.

Answer (score 1):

The cable between antenna and tuner is part of your antenna. Use oxygen-free copper wire (its a boat on salt water...). In case of a long wire connection between the feed point of your antenna and the tuner consider to place the tuner at the feed point of your antenna and use a coax cable between RX/TX and tuner.

When you use only RX than forget every recommendation and just use any wire.